# HighStock rangeSelector position with RTL

Tags: jquery, highcharts, arabic

I have a Stock Chart for arabic version of the website

**Normally it looks like that:** [image]

But when I switch to **RTL** it looks like that (pay attention at the top and bottom range selector, the numbers have to start from right to left):

[image]

It can be fixed? from API I could not find some options for that. Actually I need to fix only the range selector, the rest of the chart I can handle myself.

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsfiddle? We will check this.

Comment: It will take some time to transfer it to jsfiddle. The only change between en and ae version is that in CSS we specify `direction: rtl;` and here comes the funny part. That's all.

Comment: Meanwhile, check this [doc](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/internationalization). Note `useHTML` options, and be aware, that exporting doesn't support that flag.

Comment: I use this option all the time, but from docs the useHTML option isn't available for rangeSelector? or it is a hidden option?

Comment: About numbers, there is also information..

Comment: Ok, I'll look at that.

Comment: I have added an example to look at on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3doqcy4/1/ how you can see useHTML doesn't helped me much

Comment: Oh right, I don't know why I was all the time thinking about navigator, not rangeSelector, sorry! Indeed, `useHTML` option isn't available, reported bug [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3482). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you mate, I'll be waiting for the fix. Cheers.